# Java String.format is not working starting app as jar

Tags: java, string, formatting, executable-jar

I've got a problem with formatting a string using javas String.format.
I'm adding the string containing a description and a price to a swing JList component. I want that the prices are always under each other.

So I use:

```
String ret = String.format( "%s %-" + Integer.toString(articleNameLength) + "s %3s %9.2f EUR",
             (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")).format(date), article, " ", price );
```

You can also see the code at line 205 at:
https://github.com/hanneseilers/MyBudget/blob/master/MyBudget/src/de/hanneseilers/core/Article.java

That's working fine if I start the application using eclipse or a simple batch file that runs

```
java -jar MyBudget.ja
```

But if i use a doubleclick in file explorer to start the jar, the layout breaks up and the prices aren't under each other.
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: How are you building the jar?

Comment: Can you confirm you get different results by executing your batch file and double-clicking on the same .jar?  Specifically, are you 100% sure that you are using exactly the same .jar in both cases?  In that case, could you please upload or link to a screen capture of your UI when properly drawn and another one with it broken?

Comment: I create the jar using eclipses export feature (or the ant script that is generapted by eclipse).
I checked the batch script and it runs the same jar as I use for double clicking.
I uploaded both screenshots at:

http://imageshack.com/a/img542/9201/639v.png and 
http://imageshack.com/a/img819/4053/upda.png

I found out that using the batch script the JList component uses the  monospace font I set in my layout. If i start the jar by double click it uses default sans-serif font and that hasn't the same space for every char. But why uses one start method the correct font and the other did not?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for this.
The problem was that the application only can load a speficic monospaced font (that has same width for each character) if I start the jar using a batch script. Using a double script, java can not find the spefific font and uses default not-monospaced (irregular width for each character).

I changed the font of the JList swing component that displays the string to a not further specified monospaced font. That causes the application to load any monospaced font and it's working!

```
list.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12));
```